# Ошибка записи в базу данных mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Данный код выдает ошибку

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="colt.cityhost.com.ua",    
                        user="",        
                        passwd="",     
                        db="")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO investing_users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', ('Иван', 'Конов', 'mr_karapuz', 326545200, 'ru'))
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Я так понимаю, ошибка в кодировке базы данных, но где именно и что с этим делать?

```
File "C:\Users\Karapuz\Desktop\traine_sublime.py", line 11, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO investing_users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', ('Иван', 'Конов', 'mr_karapuz', 326545200, 'ru'))
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 199, in execute
    args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 280, in literal
    s = self.string_literal(o.encode(self.encoding))
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 188ms]
```